# A cellar suicide

Tags: mystery

A man and his wife, completely devoted to each other, have sworn to be teetotal all their lives. One of their vows at the wedding was in fact that if either of them ever drank alcohol they would take their own lives (pretty silly in my opinion).

Despite this vow the man is a brewer - though he never drinks his own brew.
The man had recently written his will giving everything he owns to his nephew.

His nephew knows this and comes round their house to celebrate New Year.

They both go down into the cellar so the nephew can inspect the latest brew. The man's wife who is washing up sees the nephew come up for some 'apple juice'.

Shortly after he goes back down, she hears her husband scream. She rushes down and sees this:

> Her husband is lying dead on the floor next to an open barrel of beer. He has blood on his shirt and a big stone lying on his stomach. His hair is wet (An investigation shows his hair is covered in beer) and he is holding a half-empty cup of **alcoholic** cider. The floor around the barrel is wet.

The nephew claims a rock fell from the ceiling and killed him. But there was no rock missing from the ceiling

**You** are called in to investigate.

> What happened and how did the man die (There's a clue in the title)

Comment: why is apple juice in quotes? Is that the wife's perspective, or the narrator, or the nephew?

Comment: @DrXorile the nephew says its apple juice but the wife doesn't check

Comment: Is there, in fact, a rock missing from the ceiling?

Comment: The wife did it. It's always the spouse.

Comment: Is there alcohol in the cider?

Comment: Ok @DrXorile there isn't added that to question. Cider is alcoholic,

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil Except when it's not

Comment: Sorry I meant *the* cider is alcoholic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be that :

> The nephew took a big rock, which was lying on top of the beer barrel to keep it closed, to knock out his uncle. That would explain the blood on his shirt from a supposed head wound. Unfortunately for the nephew, this was not enough to kill him, so the nephew put his uncle's head in the barrel and drowned him, explaining the wet hair and wet ground. Now, to make it look like a suicide he put his own cider cup in his uncle's hand, whom he knew would have to kill himself if he ever drank alcohol. Thus, he inherited the money.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: +1, but why would he make it look like suicide and then make the ridiculous claim that a rock fell from the roof?

Comment: Otherwise its murder @jhabbott and he wouldn't get his uncle's money

Comment: It doesn't add up... <spoiler> first he puts the cider glass (to make it look like suicide) then he claims it was an accident and a stone 'fell' from the roof. Well if he wanted it to look like suicide why would he claim it was an accident in an stupidly implausible way? </spoiler>

Comment: Maybe he was scared or he didn't expect the rock to fall on the man's chest and he couldn't move it before the man's wife came in so had to think quickly @jhabbott

Comment: Also, wouldn't there be more barrels around, each covered with a rock?  You're not going to make a living brewing beer one barrel at a time.

Comment: True, @DaveKaye but the question doesn't say about there only being one barrel, it merely only mentions one

Answer (score 11):

Okay, here's what happened.

> A rock fell from the ceiling and killed the man.

But how, exactly?

> The man did not properly vent this one barrel. Over time, the carbon dioxide built up enough that there was an enormous amount of pressure placed on the cap of the barrel. This pressure became too much, exploding with a violent gush of liquid gold, causing the man to scream. The barrel cap was thrown against the ceiling with such force that a large rock was dislodged directly above the man, promptly falling on his head and killing him.

This explains the scream, the open barrel, the pooled beer, the beer in the man's hair, and the circumstances of his death. The apple cider was delivered to him by his nephew and was unrelated.

---

**Edit**:

> I specifically skipped the obvious answer of "the nephew gave the man alcohol and so he killed himself or the nephew killed him and made it look like he killed himself" because I find it uninteresting. But perhaps that's the right answer?

Comment: A very similar thing once happened to me.

Comment: Yes and the hint in the title is likely referring to a "stellar suicide", somewhat of a pun on how stars explode... cellar, stellar.
That or a supernova killed him...

Comment: Sorry good answer but the title and cider are relevant

Comment: I'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: This should be the right answer!

Answer (score 3):

Even though an answer has been accepted, I'll leave my best interpretation of the events, which did in fact end with a

> suicide.

A thought:

> I had thought of a drowning, like Thrax's answer proposes, but see an issue with that timeline.  Since the wife *rushes* down after the scream (which, in Thrax's answer, is from the blow from the rock), there would be very little time to drown the uncle and then pose him with the rock and cup before the wife sees what's happening.

So here's how I see it:

> The uncle and the nephew are in the cellar, inspecting the brew, as the OP states.  The nephew leaves and returns to find the uncle having just opened a barrel, using a rock to unjam the lid.  They both peer into the brew when the nephew dunks his uncle's head into it, holding it under the beer in an attempt to drown him and claim his possessions.  The uncle fights, and gathers his strength for one push, which succeeds in freeing him from the nephew *and* lets him continue breathing.  **However**, when the uncle braced himself for that death-staving push, he inhaled some of the beer.  He coughed and sputtered and tried to catch his breath.

Then:

> Realizing that he'd inadvertantly drank beer, and had really only chosen ***death*** by his **own** hand over his nephew's, he let out a bellowing scream.  His nephew had done him in, either way, so he lifted the rock over his head, brought it crashing down, and fell into a heap with the rock on his chest.  Just as his wife found him moments later.

Therefore, it was indeed

> a cellar suicide.

Comment: Nice! I think there can be a lot of correct answers to this question

Comment: Congrats on getting 1'000 rep

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil Thanks! It's been a fun road so far, and you're well on your way yourself if you keep up the questions like this.  I want to say it has... atmosphere, which is awesome.  And there are certainly a few possibilities with this puzzle, but I'll hold my tongue on saying "a lot", just in case the TOO BROAD goblins are out there listening us.

Comment: :) I love puzzles

Comment: @raisinghellyer Don't worry about those people, they have a fundamental misunderstanding of how humans willfully engage with riddles and puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

If this was QI, this answer would no doubt get the buzzer, but...

> The man finished his apple juice and the nephew went to get some more for him.
>  The man didn't realise and picked up the nephew's cider and took a swig.
>  When the nephew returned with the apple juice, the man realised his mistake and screamed then killed himself with a large rock he kept on hand, you know, for emergencies and other eventualities.
>  The nephew ran to stop him and knocked over some beer in the process.
>  Remarkably he managed to keep hold of the cider glass.
>  The nephew lied for any one of multiple plausible reasons (he was religious and didn't like the idea of suicide, he wanted to protect his uncle's honor, he wanted to protect his aunt's feelings, he felt guilty about leaving his cider there while going to get more apple juice for his dear old uncle).

Alternatively...

> It was just like above except the nephew did it on purpose and swapped the cider/apple juice to inherit all the goodies. The beer barrel was knocked over in the man's anger before he offed himself.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer:

> The nephew drowned the father in beer and then put a half-empty cup in his hand.

Comment: Please explain how you reached this answer and why it is right.